# $T$ is a normal operator, prove any eigenspace of $T+T^*$ is invariant under $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace, normal-operator

I've been asked to prove in a homework problem exactly what the title describes. This was the $3^{rd}$ part of a question whose first 2 parts were to prove that $\ker T=\ker TT^*$ and $\ker T=\ker T^n$, but I can't find any way to implement these into this part. I've also tried proving that

$$\operatorname{Tr}[(P_{w^\bot}TP_w)(P_{w^\bot}TP_w)^*]=0$$
where $P_w$ is the projection onto the eigenspace, but I've reached the expression

$$\operatorname{Tr}[(P_{w^\bot}TP_w)(P_{w^\bot}TP_w)^*]=\operatorname{Tr}(P_wTP_wT)-\operatorname{Tr}(TP_wT)$$
and got stuck there. I would  appreciate assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $T(T+T^*) = (T+T^*)T$

Comment: You need to show that if $(T+T^*)x = \lambda x$ then $(T+T^*)Tx = \lambda Tx$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T+T^*$ and $V_{\lambda}$ is its eigenspace. We have to show that if $v\in V_{\lambda}$ then $T(v)\in V_{\lambda}$ as well. And indeed:

$(T+T^*)(Tv)=(T^2+T^*T)(v)=(T^2+TT^*)(v)=T(T+T^*)(v)=T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)$

The equality $T^*T=TT^*$ is true because $T$ is normal.